# Number of ways of cutting a squared grid into connected components

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Let $G = (V, E)$ be a squared grid graph, i.e. $V = \{1, \ldots, n\}^2$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$ and $ (u,v) \in E \iff d_{\ell_2}(u,v) = 1$.
> In how many ways can we partition $V$ into two disjoint sets $V_1, V_2$ such that the graphs induced by $V_1$ and $V_2$ are connected?

If we let $N_k$ the the number of ways in which $V$ can be partitioned such that $V_1$ has cardinality $k$ we can see that $N_1 = n^2, \; N_2 = 2 n (n-1)$. I think $N_3 = 2n(n-2) + 4(n-1)^2 $, and already $N_4$ seems very hard to compute. What is the solution?

Comment: It looks like your $N_k$ computations assume $n>k$.

Comment: Your computations seems to be done with what $V_1$ looks like. Have you considered what the cut looks like, aka the edges between a vertex of $V_1$ and a vertex of $V_2$?